# Zenject Resolve object from Project Context with dependencies from Scene Context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I have `ProjectContext` with some installers for global dependencies. One of the installers:

```cs
public class StateMachineInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
         BindStateFactory();
         BindStateMachine();
    }

    private void BindStateMachine() =>
         Container
           .BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<StateMachine>()
           .AsSingle();

    private void BindStateFactory() =>
         Container
           .BindInterfacesTo<StateFactory>()
           .AsSingle();
}
```

And I also have `SceneContext` with installer:

```cs
public class FruitsInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesTo<FruitSpawner>().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

Problem is in `StateFactory` on state creation.

```cs
public class StateFactory : IStateFactory
{
    private readonly IInstantiator _instantiator;

    public StateFactory(IInstantiator instantiator) =>
        _instantiator = instantiator;

    public IExitableState CreateState<TState>() where TState : IExitableState =>
        _instantiator.Instantiate<TState>();
}
```

In one state I have dependency from SceneContext
In this case `IFruitSpawner`.

```cs
public class GameplayState : IState
{
    private readonly IFruitSpawner _fruitSpawner;

    public GameplayState(IFruitSpawner fruitSpawner)
    {
        _fruitSpawner = fruitSpawner;
    }
 
    public void Enter() {// ...}
    public void Exit() {// ...}
}
```

But I am getting exception: `ZenjectException: Unable to resolve 'IFruitSpawner' while building object with type 'GameplayState'. Object graph: GameplayState`

How I can resolve dependencies from current `SceneContext` in `StateFactory` `CreateState<TState>()` method?

Comment: Where do you call `FruitSpawner.InstallBindings`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad this script is on the SceneContext. It calls automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inject the dependencies declared in `SceneContext` into the ones declared in `ProjectContext`. Thus you may solve it in different ways:

**option 1.** Bind `FruitSpawner` in `ProjectContext`

**option 2.** Introduce intermediary service, let's call it `SpawnerProvider` and bind it in `ProjectContext`. This service will play the role of service provider for your `FruitSpawner` (and maybe other spawners as well). Inject it as the dependency into `GameplayState`. `SpawnerProvider` should have a property/method that provides the `FruitSpawner`.

After the game scene is loaded, you should initialize the properties of this service with `FruitSpawner`. You should pay attention to the initialization order, to ensure that your `GameplayState` logic related to the spawner is executed after the `SpawnerProvider` is initialized.